# Does Alexa Widget increase Alexa Rank?

Tags: alexa

I'm not sure about this problem and I found nothing on Alexa.com talking about this problem. Anyone knows exactly that is this true?

Comment: It's not a problem.

Comment: I think It's a problem. Alexa rank is significant in some contries. If Alexa Widget doesn't improve Alexa Rank so I'll remove it from my site to lower loading time.

Comment: Do you honestly believe having an Alexa widget on your website will magically increase your Alexa ranking? Why does Alexa ranking matter? Google will not view your Alexa ranking and move your website up the search results? Google will though surely take into consideration the time it takes your website to load. That's a fact. Remove the widget Alexa rankings are stupid and useless.

Comment: Familiarise yourself with how Alexa ranks websites: http://www.alexa.com/help/traffic-learn-more

Comment: I would think people would want to have shared access to you Google Analytics account to view your daily visits and page views for them selves before buying ad space.

Comment: Both Alexa and Google Analytics. Alexa is also a reference. Because  the leak of knowledge about IT, many people believe that Alexa is an important info. Alexa is also used to PR the website, eg: **http://wikibiz.vn is in top 100 site** (according to Alexa).

Comment: I have read it helps increase the rank because they would check your site more often but im not sure if it works that way though.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking at it from a marketing perspective where you want to have a High pagerank then you need to focus your efforts on Google / Bing and other important sites.  Having a high Alexa page rank is only valuable if you are in the business of selling advertising space on your site.   If you are, then maybe QUantCast is a better option for you.

As for the alexa widget, I would assume you can lazy load it if you are worried about performance.  Just write a bit of Jquery to append the code after the page has fully loaded.  You might be able to use the defer option in the script (does not always work for all code so test it).

Lastly, most of Alexa rankings used to come from the Alexa toolbar.   Not too many people install the toolbar, so the rankings are not all that accurate.