# How to improve the Alexa rank of my website?

Tags: ranking, alexa

I have good number of visits to my website, but my Alexa rank is as low (in the millions). How can I improve my Alexa rank?

Answer (score 3):

Alexa simply counts the number of unique visitors to a website. Install the Alexa <s>spyware</s> [toolbar](http://www.alexa.com/toolbar) and visit your website once a day. Your ranking will skyrocket.

Alexa is completely useless as a metric of any kind. I wouldn't spend any time worrying about it.

Comment: I already intalled the Alexa toolbar  6 months ago, but my rank is not improving.

Comment: You need to get more people with that toolbar installed to visit your site. Also, try installing their widget on your site. I don't know if they use it for counting purposes but if they do that will help a lot.

Comment: Alexa also skews in favor for certain types of sites and activity. For example, blogs always rank higher. Topic is also an issue. Temporal topics such as celebrities and politics will rank higher. Part of the reason is not traffic as much as attracting people who are more social and topical will likely have an Alexa toolbar or 3rd a party toolbar based upon Alexa installed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Alexa Tool Bar: [Download Alexa Toolbar for your browser](http://www.alexa.com/toolbar).
2. Claim your site.
3. Put Alexa Widget on your blog.

Comment: See also: [Does Alexa Widget increase Alexa Rank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38238/does-alexa-widget-increase-alexa-rank)